# call mysql stored procedure through vba

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have created a stored procedure in mysql workbench located on server. I need to call this stored procedure through a vba application located on local machine. I am stuck on it unable to connect to mysql stored procedure. Thanks in advance for responses .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question doesn't have much detail and so others will likely find it difficult to help you. Take a look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to learn more about how you can improve your question and make it as open as you can for people to help.

Comment: Google and SO search are your friends. Look for examples, try something yourself and then come back here with your sample code, results and any errors you received. In short - show an effort - it's apprciated and well rewarded here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/185125

Comment: @dbmitch i already did try some of the solutions but vba is unable to find the stored procedure and if possible without ADO.

Comment: "then come back here with your sample code, results and any errors you received"

Comment: [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup a DSN with an ODBC connection yet?
Assuming so - check out simple  examples at

It wasn't hard to find this on Google

[DAO Examples](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/184749)